# Is there a way to "unminimize" a window from the terminal?

Tags: 20.04, window-manager, wmctrl

I'm making a small GUI extension, one of the things with which it struggles however are minimized windows (I do a lot of window moving via `wmctrl`). I heard that it is impossible to minimize windows with wmctrl (which it probably should be), so I assume that "un-minimizing" would be impossible as well, still worth the ask though.

Comment: Minimizing in `wmctrl` works by adding the `hidden` property (option `-b`).

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Yes it does, thank you! :D